# Replace certain strings from text with SED and REGEX

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following strings in a text file (big one, more like these and different):

```
79A18D7F-1517-5981-8446-3A0452727B06
7842A72D-1517-5281-84E4-EAEF09B743F7
6040BEE7-1517-5982-84C1-419B224E647E
615F2747-1517-5981-84AF-787C34967FB2
7468A3E3-1517-5931-84B3-3FC3F701C269
```

I can find them using grep and regex:

```
'[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}'
```

what's the sed regex syntax to delete them because:

```
sed "s/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}//g"
```

doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sed -r`.  You are relying on extended regular expression syntax features without escaping them, but with `sed -r` you don't have to.  If you want to actually delete the lines instead of just clearing them, you can use:

```
sed -r "/regex/d"
```

Comment: No, is ok, I just want to delete the string not line.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, for regular sed (BRE) you would need to escape the curly braces:

```
sed 's/[0-9A-F]\{8\}-[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9A-F]\{4\}-[0-9A-F]\{12\}//g' file
```